# How can I fill a ListBox using data of a Column of a DataGridVeiw?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, listbox

I have two windows forms. In the first form I have a `DataGridView` and search button. Wen I click search, the grid fills by data from a `DataTable` which is returned by a stored procedure. I to need take single column from this `DataGridView` and fill a `Listbox` in another form.
How I can fill `ListBox` in second form, from values of column at index 3 of first form ?

```
DT = rec.AdvancdSearch(txtname.Text.ToString(),int.Parse(cmblocation.SelectedValue.ToString()), cmbstatus.Text.ToString(), txtfrom.Text.ToString(), txtto.Text, cbmgendr.Text, int.Parse(cbmjob.SelectedValue.ToString()));
dataGridView1.DataSource = DT;
if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count < 2)
{
    MessageBox.Show("عذراً لم يتم العثور على اى نتائج بحث مطابقة للبينات المدخلة", "عملية البحث", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    lblcount.Text = "لا يوجد نتائج";
}
else
{
    lblcount.Text = "نتائج البحث \n" + (dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1);
}
```

Comment: In which part you have a problem? Adding values of a column to `ListBox` or Passing values to another form?

Comment: i dont know how i can get data from datagridview column to listbox 
note : datagridview and listbox not in the same form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Get values**

As an option you can select values of column at index 3 of `DataGridView` this way:

```
var list = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                        .Where(x => !x.IsNewRow)
                        .Select(r => r.Cells[3].Value.ToString())
                        .ToList();
```

Also you can get values from `DataTable`:

```
var list = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(r => r.Field<string>(3)).ToList();
```

**Pass Values to another Form**

After getting the list, you should pass values to another form this way:

```
var f2 = new Form2(list);
f2.Show();
```

To be able to to write `var f2 = new Form2(list);` and pass the list to you your second form, you should change the constructor of that form to accept a value of type `List<string>`:

```
List<string> list;
public Form2 (List<string> l)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    list= l;
    this.listBox1.DataSource = list;
}
```

**Show in ListBox**

As you can see above, in second form, its enough to use:

```
this.listBox1.DataSource = list;
```

Also you can add items:

```
this.listBox1.Items.AddRange(list.ToArray());
```

Comment: thank you its worked well but how i can duplicate the operation and ad another column values to the same listbox without open new form and add the new result in it ?

Comment: ListBox can only have one column. What is your requirement?

Comment: the form 1 is search form every time the gridveiw show diffrent values i need to add the current value to the listbox and make search in form1 again the gridview result will be changed i need to add the new result to the old one its i has passed to listbox the past time 
you got it ? 
i think i just  need to make the second form static !!?

Comment: No, add a public method to your second form: `public void AddItems(List<string> list){listBox1.Items.AddRange(list.ToArray());}` Then instead of passing items in constructor, pass items using this method after you show the form.

Comment: Also, don't create an instance of the form each time. Create the instance of second form just once.

Comment: you mean add method         
public  list<string> AddItems(List<string> list) { listBox1.Items.AddRange(list.ToArray()); }
and passing the item like that
            this.listBox1.Items.Add(AddItems(list));
 ?

Comment: Yes. this way, each time you ca the method on the instance of your form and pass new values, those values add to the `ListBox`.

Comment: i tried to add method 
public list<string> AddItems(List<string> list) { listBox1.Items.AddRange(list.ToArray()); } 

note i makes it to return list not void 
and in constructor i replaced 
this.listBox1.DataSource = list;
with
this.listBox1.Items.Add(AddItems(list));
but every time i clicked the button new form open and add the current result in new listbox not the same form and the same listbox

Comment: 1- The method should be void. You don't need return any value. 2- forget about constructor. Just create an instance of second form for the first time and keep a rafarance to it in a form level variable (Form2 f2;) 3- Each time you want to add items to the `ListBox` of form2, call f2.AddItems(list)

Comment: If you couldn't make it work, feel free to ask another question and share what you have tried and I'll try to solve the problem :)